# How can I show image from express server on Vue app?

Tags: mysql, node.js, image, vue.js, express

I'm currently having problem with displaying image from db. In my DB (Sequelize MySQL), my columns looks like this.
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4q5md.png)

You can see that there is path, which is showing path to file on server. (Express server using multer to upload photos).

How Am I able to show this on my frontend? I was trying everything, but I cannot figure solution.
When I open my server folder and copy path of file there, I get path like this:
[Path](http://file:///Users/zacik/Desktop/BOZP_LOCAL/bozp-api/static/uploads/4d8abca2bbf1381b6aa9c45879342b62.png)
When I put it in chrome, I can see that image, but when I try to display it in frontend, I'm not that lucky.

Here is my function on backend to get image.

```
async getOneImage (req,res){
    try{
        const getOneImage = await CaseImage.findOne({ where: {CaseId: req.params.CaseId, id: req.params.id}});

        if (getOneImage == null) {
            res.status(400).send({ message: 'Prípad so zadaným ID sa nenašiel.' });
        }

        res.send(getOneImage);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(400).send({ message: 'Nepodarilo sa načítať fotografie, skúste to neskôr.'});
    }
},
```

Maybe should I change that response to binary or? I don't understand this topic cleary as you can see.

Thank you all for help and sorry if question is not correctly formated or named.

---

Ok so I tried, now I have request to node server but I get response 404 cannot get... so I'm assuming that problem is somewhere in my express settings...

this.imageSrc = `http://localhost:3000/${data.path}.png`

this is full url.. but response is 404.

http://localhost:3000/static/uploads/70e13f7cd5e6a3d0a0d0bc252d62fa31.png

edit.

So, this is my front-end.. You can see that I'm sending response to correct path.
[frontend request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4q5md.png)

Here you can see how my backend setting of express looks like.
[Express](http://file:///Users/zacik/Desktop/BOZP_LOCAL/bozp-api/static/uploads/4d8abca2bbf1381b6aa9c45879342b62.png)

And here is response that I'm getting when I send request to backend.
[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J21wb.png)

But I'm still not able to see image in vue. When I check I see only blank space and in console is this reply:

"GET http://localhost:3000/static/uploads/70e13f7cd5e6a3d0a0d0bc252d62fa31.png 404 (Not Found)"

And in network tab is this.
[Network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9Ffa.png)

Comment: Can you show how the call to back-end is done from your front-end part?

Comment: your sending json back not the actual image, you need to either load the image from the path via a `<img :src="image.path"/>` tag, or load the actual image with fs, then pipe etc in express and send it back, then use an  `<img src="/path/to/the/route"/>`

Comment: Here is my call o back-end.. [link] (https://pastebin.com/qcPwkmwb) .. now I can see one big problem and that I'm requesting wrong database. I should request database, when Images are not cases..

Answer (score 0):

If you have correct paths to the images in your database you simply render them with an  tag. Make sure the path to the file is complete, or relative to your static assets folder.

In your case the path seems to be some mix of static/uploads/hash and the filename problem.png.

This means the full url to the file is most likely something like:

domain.com/static/uploads//.png. The domain.com part will most likely be localhost: if you are working locally. On a production server this will be your domain you are hosting your app on.

PS. your second image is a full file path on your system, this wont be visible on a server.

Answer (score 0):

So you have this static folder.

If you are not already serving this static folder with express, see this [explanation](https://expressjs.com/de/starter/static-files.html) on how to serve a static folder.

Once you fetch your image in the frontend you will have an image object something like this:

```json
{
     "id": 1,
     "fileName": "problem.png",
     "mimeType". "image/png",
     "caseId: 2,
     "path": "static/uploads/abcdefg.......png"
}
```

Your img tag in your html file should look as follows.

```html
<img src="http://localhost:{PORT_OF_EXPRESS_SERVER}/static/uploads/abcdefg.........png"/>
```

Because you're using vue.js here is an example with axios.

MyComponent.js

```js
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
    data: () => {
         return {
              imageUrl: ''
         }
    },
    mounted(): async () => {
         // this route here must match what you defined in your backend
         const { data } = await axios.get('/image/2/5')
         console.log(data);
         /** {
             "id": 1,
             "fileName": "problem.png",
             "mimeType". "image/png",
             "caseId: 2,
             "path": "static/uploads/abcdefg.......png"
             } **/

         // now we set the imageUrl, assuming your express port is 1337
         this.imageUrl = `http://localhost:1337/${data.path}`; 
    }
}
```

MyComponent.html

```html
<template>
    <div id="my-component">
         <img :src="imageUrl"/>
    </div>
</template>
<script src="./MyComponent.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply!.. In my server.js I have this: app.use(express.static('public')); ..
When I send request to. backend to get one image, I get this response: 
{
caseId: 1
createdAt: "2021-08-20T09:39:07.000Z"
fileName: "problem.png"
id: 33
mimeType: "image/png"
path: "static/uploads/70e13f7cd5e6a3d0a0d0bc252d62fa31"
updatedAt: "2021-08-20T09:39:07.000Z"
}..
But when I use img tag as you send me, I still get res 404 not found..

Comment: <img src="http://localhost:3000/static/images/photo.png" />